# bootstrap - смена позиционирования блока

Tags: css, bootstrap

С использованием `bootsrtap` создано два блока:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12>
    <p>Тут какой-то текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12>
    <p>Тут второй текст</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при экране `xs`, второй блок становился выше первого?

Answer (score 1):

В 4ом бутстрапе для определения порядка элементов есть [класс `.order-*`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#order):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 order-2 order-sm-1">
      <p>Первый блок</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 order-1 order-sm-2">
      <p>Второй блок, при экране xs, становится выше первого</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Подробней [на сайте](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-6 col-xs-12">
      <p>Тут второй текст</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-pull-6 col-xs-12">
      <p>Тут какой-то текст</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: суть в том, что так я пробовал.он просто уводит блок запределы экраны и все.а мне нужно чтобы он именно при уменьшении экрана только так делал..а при большом экране все оставалось на своих местах

Comment: @Deniskins Код, который я привел полностью корректный. Если код уводит элементы за пределы экрана, значит не правильно расставлены классы, скорее всего у Вас первым идет pull, а вторым push.

Comment: самое интересное, что в моем случае они не работают.хотя в разметке именно так все и есть и ничего не добавлено.внутри блоков разве что контент,а не текст..а в итоге блоки просто уходят за границы монитора и видно лишь краешек.

Answer (score 0):

Выше вам дали правильный ответ, только

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-xs-12">
    <p>Первый блок на XS</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-xs-12">
    <p>Второй блок на XS</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Здесь нужно начинать думать с XS, то есть первый будет первым на XS а на остальных размерах регулировать с помощью push/pull

Comment: дмитрий, поясни плиз - первый блок будет первым только на xs, а в остальных случаях будет вторым?то есть в sm тоже необходимо указывать pull и push?Поясню - при больших экранах блоки расположены в одну горизонтальную линию, а пр маленьких в столбец.

Comment: push/pull необходимо указывать на тех разрешениях где нужно поменять блоки местами. Если напишешь col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-push-6, то, соответсвенно, блоки поменяются месами на md. Грубо говоря, если смотреть разметку, push перемещает блок вниз, а pull вверх

Comment: самое интересное, что в моем случае они не работают.хотя в разметке именно так все и есть и ничего не добавлено.внутри блоков разве что контент,а не текст..а в итоге блоки просто уходят за границы монитора и видно лишь краешек.

Comment: только что заметил - если применять pull и push к sm, то работает, меняет местами.а если к xs, он сразу уводит один блок налево за пределы экрана, а второй направо так же за пределы экрана и это на любом размере экрана.в чем может быть причина и как исправить?

Comment: без примера гадать не могу, киньте ссылку или в песочницу залейте

Answer (score 0):

```css
[class*=col-] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-push-6 col-md-push-6 col-sm-push-6">
    <p>Тут второй текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-pull-6 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-pull-6">
    <p>Тут какой-то текст</p>
  </div>
</div>
```